# Any better way to export double quote csv data from string object in Xquery

Tags: xquery, marklogic

It is common to export list of strings as double quote csv format in log file with Xquery for ML.

I wonder whether there is better way to do so from the list of the strings.
Currently I have to use a lot of `fn:concat('"', $value , '"')` block to do it.
It becomes difficult to read if there is a long list of values to process.

Below is the current code for a simple demo case.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $values := ('string 1', 'string 2', 'string N')

return fn:string-join( $values ! fn:concat('"', . , '"'), ',')
```

The expected output is `"string 1","string 2","string N"`

Comment: You can write your own function that takes a singe parameter (e.g. `declare function local:wrap($value)`) and does `concat('"', $value, '"')` in the function body so that your main expression can be reduced to `string-join($values ! local:wrap(.), ',')`. I would think that the whole process of conversion also might need to escape or double double quotes inside of each value. And I don't know Marklogic details, of course there might be built-in ways or formats for easy conversion to CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to wrap every value in quotes, you could simplify slightly to something like the below.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $values := ('string 1', 'string 2', 'string N')

return '"' || fn:string-join($values, '","') || '"'
```

Answer (score 1):

With generic XQuery 3.1, you can elegantly build up the CSV values using the [arrow operator](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-arrow-operator):

```
xquery version "3.1";

let $values := ('string 1', 'string 2', 'string N')
return
    $values
    => for-each( function($value) { '"' || $value || '"' } )
    => string-join(",")
```

Depending on the content of your values, you might need to apply some escaping - e.g., of commas or quotation marks.

This could easily be wrapped into a function, e.g., `local:create-csv-row($values)`.